# How to implement 3rd layer child component

Tags: angular

app.component is my top layer.
- child layer 1
--child layer 2.

I want to use `<app-childlayer2></app-childlayer2>` in child-layer1.html.

what import and declarations I will have to make in app-module.ts and app-childlayer1.ts?

can this be done without adding module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there is nothing any special import or declaration you have to do separately. Use **ng generate component** command to create new components and it will automatically modify your app.module.ts. Use the following commands to make a good folder structure.

```
ng g c components/child-layer-1
ng g c components/child-layer-1/child-layer-2
...
```

Also use @input, @ouput decorators to share data between components
https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76
.

If is there anything should be changed, Please comment @others

Comment: Thanks. I recreated my components using ng generate command and it worked. I think I was updating dependencies correctly when I created components manually.